# Is co.cc actually free?

Tags: domains

i have a co.cc domain before. it is stated that renewal is free for personal use. but i have a doamin i used previously that requires $3 for renewal. is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to www.co.cc, yes it's free *for personal use*. If you are being billed then you should contact support at co.cc. You may need to prove the domain is for personal use only - if you have ads on there, you won't have a good case.

Incidentally, `.cc` domains are for "Cocos (Keeling) Islands, an Australian territory" according to Wikipedia. So unless your site is targeted to that area then it's not really wise to use that TLD, even if it is free.

Domains are only a few bucks a year, why not shell out for one? `.com` may be $10 or more but country-specific ones are much cheaper. `.co.uk` for example is not more than £3/year.

Comment: i am thinking after i earned some money then get a domain. i know its cheap. but i am a student and dont really want to spend too much. anyway i dont have a credit card so its harder to spend online currently

Comment: is it a good idea to get a co.cc domain for now, and plan to get a domain+hosting before 1 year. then redirect users from the co.cc to .com? maybe its not the best for SEO?